# Oracle Apex - If one page is changed will users of app have to log in again?

Tags: oracle-apex

If I change one page in an apex application will all current users even if they are not using this page have to log into the application again and lose the current session state for that user?  Or will current users who are not accessing the page not be affected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no one should need to login again.  That's the beauty of APEX - when your changes are made to a page, all users will realize those changes the very next time they load the page.  All in-flight session state should be preserved and usable.

The only caveat - if you introduce logic changes to a page that depend upon items newly added to a page, then you may wish to force the expiration of in-flight sessions.  Because otherwise, the users who are in the middle of sessions could encounter some odd behavior.

Comment: Thanks that's consistent to what my testing found - that changes on pages not being viewed don't always (never?) require I user to log on again.